# Angular: Route using query paramters

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is there a way to have `router-outlet` route to url path based on given query parameters?

I know that Angular provides '/' based selective url paths - `base/tab/2`.

```
MyModule.ts
  ...
    RouterModule.forChild([
       ...
       {
         path: 'tag/:id',
         component: TagDetailComponent
       }]);
  ...
```

But is there a way to have a url with queryParameter e.g. `base?tab=2` and route to specific component based on the value of the querypParam.

Comment: It is possible, you can conditionally show a component inside the base component based on the query parameter.

Comment: @Ploppy, could you please provide an example with detail.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but not through **router-outlet**. You can write your **own version of router-outlet** and in that, you can subscribe to queryparams and render components accordingly either by *ngIf/ngSwitch or you can dynamically inject them via factory.